# Dropbear for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, server, dropbear

I'm looking for an open source SSH server for Windows.
I came across a some servers but they were all closed source.
I want to believe that one exists already.

I also tried to compile Dropbear for Windows using Cygwin, but that involves some more dlls and i'm not sure if the result is identical to the Linux Dropbear.

Another approach I though of is to port the Dropbear source for Windows (i.e change the APIs in the code).
Can anyone recommend a good open source?  Or came across a good port project?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using cygwin why not just use openssh that you can get as a package with it?

Comment: I dont want to use Cygwin since I'm not sure if the application for Windows does not have "side affects" (caused by the change in the APIs from Linux to Windows)

Comment: If you ssh into Cygwin you could run the command under `cmd /c command` which should put you back in a windows context, as though you were at a `cmd` prompt